# Trying to create a Mongo view to flatten the data

Tags: mongodb-query

I've been trying to create a Mongo View, but looking for help.
I have records structured like this in Mongo and am trying to flatten the structure using a view for a reporting solution:

```
{
    "_id" : "`1",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2021-03-11T12:30:26.000+0000"),
    "tags" : [
        {
            "key" : "documentType",
            "value" : "OTHER"
        },
        {            
            "key" : "TYPE",
            "value" : "DOCUMENT"        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2021-03-11T12:30:51.000+0000"),
    "tags" : [
        {
            "key" : "relatesTo",
            "value" : "123456"
        },
        {
            "key" : "TYPE",
            "value" : "VIDEO"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2021-03-19T08:13:00.000+0000"),
    "tags" : [
        {
            "key" : "TYPE",
            "value" : "VIDEO"
        }
    ]
}
```

The tag key/value pairs can differ significantly, but what I'm trying to achieve is a view that outputs roughly like this:

```
Id    relatesTo     type        documentType
============================================
1                   DOCUMENT    OTHER   
2     123456        VIDEO
3                   VIDEO
```

Is this possible?
If so, how? I'm struggling to work out how to obtain the value for a specific key in the tags array, and then trying to include that in a projection.

Can't seem to find anything overly helpful from googling, although I'm sure this must have been asked before.

Any help seriously appreciated.
Thanks!